# Пара задач по Perl

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать пару тестовых заданий по Perl (сделать небольшие пояснения).

**V.** Чему равно `$1` после выполнения?

```perl
$_ = "Happy new 2004 year";
/^.*(\d+) year$/;
```

- Happy new
- appy new 2004
- Happy new 2004
- 2
- 4
- 2004

**VII.** В чём кроется потенциальная опасность следующего оператора?

```perl
$string =~ s/$substring//;
```

Можете ли вы предложить способ избежать проблемы?

**VIII.** Чему равно `$1` после выполнения?

```perl
$_ = "Lambada 2004";
/([0-4]*)/;
```

- 4
- 004
- 2
- 2004
- пустой строке
- Lambada (после последнего символа "a" -- пробел)

**IX.** Дана строка, представляющая собой вызов функции в C.
Известно, что круглые скобки корректно сбалансированы и имеют уровень вложенности <= 1. Комментарии внутри вызова не допускаются.

Необходимо выделить из строки аргументы функции (например, дано f(x, y(z)), нужно выделить x, y(z) ) .
Какое из предложенных ниже регулярных выражений вы будете использовать для этой цели?

- `\([^()]*?\)`
- `\([^()]*\)`
- `\(.*\)`
- `\(.*?\)`
- `\(([^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)`
- `\([^()]*(\([^()]\))*\)`
- `\([^()]*(\(.*\))*\)`
- предложите свой вариант

Спасибо.

Comment: Это же тестовые задания из формы вакансии на Яндексе :)

Comment: Мне от этого не легче :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гм. Ну, раз не легче, тогда ловите ответы. Хотя половина задач решается просто запуском кода в интерпретаторе.

V. Правильный ответ — `4`. Точка со звездочкой съедят всю строку, затем механизм регулярок начнет отступать, пока не обеспечит совпадение остатка выражения; как только он отступит за четверку, всё выражение совпадет.

VII. Ну тут хрен его знает, где там прямо «опасность» хотят увидеть… Скорее всего, имелось в виду, что переменная может содержать мета-символы, которых на самом деле матчить не хотелось; в этом случае, выражение нужно записать так:

```
$string =~ s/\Q$substring\E//;
```

Хотя можно порассуждать еще за компиляцию регэкспов и еще за кое-что.

VIII. Правильный ответ — `пустой строке`. Любое выражение под звездой Клини совпадает с пустой строкой. Здесь нет больше никаких якорей и других ограничений, так что группировка (в скобках) совпадет сразу с «ничем».

IX. Правильный ответ — `\(([^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)`. Про поиск вложенных конструкций можно поэму сочинить.

Comment: На интерпретаторе-то давно уже прокрутил всё...просто хочется понять, как всё на самом деле происходит...)
Правильно ли я понял, что перлисты обычно занимаются только регулярными выражениями? Или там всё попроще?

Спасибо за ответ. (для Вашего рейтинга надо кликнуть thumb up?)

Comment: Перлисты занимаются регулярками не чаще, чем другие. Ну, не намного чаще :)

Comment: Если хотите поблагодарить, то кликните thumb up и примите ответ (там галочка должна быть).

Comment: Накинул 10 очков...thumb up не кликнуть (рейтинг у меня печальный)...)

Comment: А, не надо было меня награждать. Я их теперь и вернуть не могу, пока вы сами на чей-нибудь вопрос не ответите. Перечислять свои очки уважения торопиться не надо, это уже слишком. Достаточно оценить/принять ответ.

Comment: Ок...)
А Вы перлист?)

Comment: угу

↓ комментарии кончились. По вопросу ниже — заработать можно. Спрос на нас, перловщиков, небольшой, но стабильный. Зарплаты нормальные.

Comment: Москва?)
Я из Питера...)
Просто хочется понять, если прекрасно заботать Perl, то можно хорошо зарабатывать? Я Вот уже второй день его читаю: вроде нравится...)

Answer (score 0):

Дополняют ответ на 7 вопрос: есть еще функция quotemeta. Можно и её использовать

Comment: Ок...спасибо)

$string = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog';
$substring = 'quick.*?fox';
$quoted_string = quotmeta($substring);
$sentence =~ s/$quoted_substring/$string/;